Problem with xpath expression: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Jaxen XPath selection failed
I am using jasperreports and Jaxen to parse xml documents. I am trying to evaluate xpath (in fact Jasperreports does it) on this xml:
<myprefix:car xmlns:myprefix="http://cars/1.1" >
    <myprefix:owner>
    </myprefix:owner>
 </myprefix:car>

I get this exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Jaxen XPath selection failed. Expression: //myprefix:car/myprefix:owner
I used this expressions:

//myprefix:car/myprefix:owner
/myprefix:car/myprefix:owner
//myprefix:car//myprefix:owner
//*[local-name()='car']/[local-name()='owner']

and I get always exception that parse failed.
I want to make it parsable and I need two instructions:

find all such nodes or
find first such node

I have xml with namespaces but I would like to use a solution that uses local names, without namespaces but I would be also interested in testing solution with namespaces.

Look for some mechanism in the XPath API to bind namespace prefixes to URIs. Alternatively, I believe Jaxen supports XPath 2.0 so you may be able to write //Q{http://cars/1.1}car/Q{http://cars/1.1}owner. Also in 2.0 you can do //*:car/*:owner to match in any namespace.
